# What's the easiest way to play youtube video in <video>tag in React

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to play youtube video in html5  tag but I am getting some error

```
<div className={classes.VideoContainer}>
    <video
      className={classes.movieInfo__trailer}
      src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3hy2aLQFrI"
      type="video/mp4"
      autoPlay
      controls
    ></video>
  </div>
```

I am getting "No video with supported format and MIME type found" error

Comment: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can try to use `iframe` instead of the `video`

from

```
   <div className={classes.VideoContainer}>
        <video
          className={classes.movieInfo__trailer}
          src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3hy2aLQFrI"
          type="video/mp4"
          autoPlay
          controls
        ></video>
      </div>
```

to

```
  <div className={classes.VideoContainer}>
       <iframe
          width="560"
          height="400"
          className={classes.movieInfo__trailer}
          src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3hy2aLQFrI"
          type="video/mp4"
          autoPlay
          controls
        ></iframe>
      </div>
```

Comment: how can we trigger an event on video end with iframe ?

Comment: can you explain more detail , I am not  get  the ur question?